# Sound generator: 14500Hz frequenzy (required), 90db (required), should run ~24days on battery (if reasonable)

Tags: battery-operated, sound

I am looking to build the following thing:

Sound generator: 14500 Hz frequency (required), 95 dB measured at source (required), should run ~24 days on battery (if reasonable).

There are two major phases:

1. **Prototype:** Needs to be easy enough for an non electronic guy like me to build. I have seen videos on the 555 chip, some calculations.
2. **Series:** If the prototype is conclusive I might first build a series of 50 and then several 10000.

I have read that differences of sin and square waves are marginal in tone output if the frequency is >10 kHz. How much is marginal on a frequency at 14500 Hz.

Currently I hope to have max change of frequency ±200 Hz as an output.

I am looking for ideas:

- What would be the most reasonable circuit to build to generate this frequency. (est. material cost?)
- How can I select the best speaker for this application (very economic, low energy consumption, ..?)

Comment: By far the easiest thing would be to program some tiny little microprocessor to put out a 14.5 kHz square wave. Use a bridge to drive the speaker. Possibly, adding a capacitor in series with the speaker will improve efficiency. This product must not be used near people. It will drive them completely crazy.

Comment: Please note, 90dB is not a valid specification. dB is always relative to some standard. For example dBA is a sound pressure related to the "A" weighted reference level. Also, sound pressure is not usually measured at source, but at some defined distance from source. You will need to refine your specification to a well-defined sound pressure, then you will need to select a speaker capable of such output. You may be able to use a piezo-electric element instead of a typical tweeter type speaker.

Comment: Is the purpose of this to annoy / drive away teenagers?  If so, don't do that.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware but mother's day is not celebrated on the 2nd sunday in May in the UK (it was in March this year) and neither is this site a forum. Also, for your information, 95 dB means zilch unless you relate it to some other measurement.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a prototype to confirm whether a insect can be releaved from a plaque. the soud is supposed to not disturb the insect but prevent its plague from eating the insect's blood. the whole setting will be inside a wooden box in some distance to people, therefore limited interfearance if any is expected. ( to be confirmed during prototyping). Any specific microprocessor with a crystal oscillator, horn or piezo electric element you would reccomend? i think 90 dbA at 1 m is good enough to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall that for 90dB SPL you need about 1W of power (given how terribly inefficient most speakers are). If we look at 24 days, that is about 90000 seconds. That would thus be 90000 Watt seconds. Assuming no efficiency losses in anything else, given a 4.5V battery, that would still require a whopping 20Ah. That's already getting into very large batteries (and I would be surprised if you get even close to that number in practice, the efficiency of your driving circuit could be poor too and you would need even more power).

This also means that you don't need to look too much at the power of your oscillator (It will insignificant compared to the few Watt you will need for your actual audio output). I would suggest looking at something like a microprocessor with a crystal oscillator. It is overkill, but easiest and cheap in low volume. I think it will also be the easiest way to get a nice accurate tone. In volume production, I would be surprised if the generator circuitry costs more than a dollar/euro or two. Your main cost will be the batteries.

Comment: At that frequency, a piezo driver would be quite efficient - at least a lot more than any (cone) speaker. Some I´ve seen will give 94dB @ 1W/1m, so you could halve that power requirement of 1W.  :)

Comment: Normal voice coil speakers are breathtakingly inefficient, but they can be made much better either by adding a horn or using a resonant piezoelectric transducer instead of a broadband speaker.

Comment: Wouldn't one use a piezo in this kind of single-tone setup?